# how to get AR model coefficients of order 10 in matlab

Tags: time-series, regression, matlab

I have a matrix which is yielded by two grayscale images subtraction. I wish to use this matrix to fit it to an Autoregressive Model of order 10 using matlab. After that I only want to extract the 10 coefficients from it. I did the following code:

```
 %b is my matrix in a vector form 
 m = ar(b,10); 
 %this returns me 10 values, positive and negatives 
 p=getpvec(m)
```

Is this the correct way? are there other different ways to do the same?

Comment: Looks okay. But why don't you feed the AR filter with an impulse response and verify that for yourself?

Comment: @EitanT: how to do this?

Comment: I suggest that read more about [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html), [`impulse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/impulse.html) and [`impz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/impz.html)...

Comment: @EitanT: This filter must me applied in the coefficients after the model is calculated?

Comment: Well, yes. You're applying the filter with the calculated coefficients to see if you're obtaining a signal that is similar to `b`.